# Why isn't my normal map working

Tags: uv, node-editor, topology, normal-map

I wanted my retopology mesh to look like it has more detail so I decided to make a bake an image texture that I could use as a normal map. The detail isn't showing instead I get this

[image: picture]

Also if you know any better ideas about what you need to do after retopologizing (how to make retopo mesh look like a high res mesh) please tell them.

Comment: could you please pack the images and share the file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I fixed it, In the 'bruh' node I changed the generated setting to a single image. Thanks for trying to help tho.